# How come the content of this if statement is getting executed when false?

Tags: ruby

I am very confused when I comment out `winning_array = current_array`the if statement will correctly print "true" or "false" if the test is true or false. But when `winning_array = current_array` is included, winning_array always equals current_array and false is always being printed, like both the if and the else are being executed.. but true is never printed. I'm guessing that something is going on that I just don't understand at my level yet.

```
thousand_array.each do |x|
    current_array.delete_at(0)
    current_array << x   # Delete first number and add current number to array

    puts "current: #{current_array}"
    puts "winning: #{winning_array}"

    if current_array.inject(:*) > winning_array.inject(:*)
        puts "true"
        #winning_array = current_array
    else
        puts "false"
    end
end
```

Comment: Perhaps you need `==` where you have `=`. If `b` is neither `nil` nor `false`, `a = b` always returns a "truthy" value (i.e., `b`). `a == b` returns `true` if the values are the same, else `false`.

Comment: I don't understand, I am assigning the value using `=`, not making a comparison.

Comment: What I am saying is that the conditional statement of my if statement seems to be affecting the actual test of my if statement. Again, I think this is me misinterpreting what is going on.

Comment: I don't follow. If you set `winning_array = current_array`, then `current_array.inject(:*) > winning_array.inject(:*)` is the same as `winning_array.inject(:*) > winning_array.inject(:*)`, which returns `false`.

Comment: Look at where the comment is at the bottom, that is what I am referring to.

Comment: Are you expecting `winning_array = current_array` to copy the contents of `current_array` to `winning_array`? That's not how it works, you just end up with two references to the same array so the `current_array.delete_at(0)` and `current_array << x` on the next iteration will change `winning_array` too (because then `current_array.object_id == winning_array.object_id`).

Comment: Well, if `true` is not printed, `winning_array = current_array` (if uncommented) is not being executed,  Why do you think `current_array.inject(:*) > winning_array.inject(:*)` is `true`?

Comment: Could you  be looking at the following? `puts 'true`' is executed, `winning_array = current_array` is executed, then `current_array` is changed, so the next thing you might see is `false` being printed. I assume you've inserted some `puts` statements (especially for `winning_array` and `currrent_array`).

Comment: I understand exactly what is happening now, as Mu Is Too Short is pointing out, I have one array and that is why they are both equal. The test must pass as true the first time which is too far back for me to see. After it is true the first time, both arrays actually reference the same array. I misunderstood the `=` operator for arrays, thank you.